# How to prevent or block suspension upload an html video being uploaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following example

```
<video id="miVideo" preload="auto" controls="controls" src="http://media.w3.org/2010/05/bunny/movie.mp4" suspend="none"></video>
```

Where suspend = "none" means that I want the video not to be suspended at any time, which happens to me in Google Chrome. In Mozilla Firefox version 4.9 does not present this inconvenience.

Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: `suspend` does not appear to be a real attribute on the `<video>` tag. Can you explain in a different way exactly what you want?

Comment: That's not what suspend does: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/suspend

Comment: suspend = "none" is just an example, I want it not to suspend buffering.